# How do I prevent an edit control in multiline mode from hiding partial lines of text?

Tags: windows, winapi, textbox, multiline

I have a scrollable multi-line edit control (class EDIT, with ES_MULTILINE and WS_VSCROLL/ES_AUTOVSCROLL) which is sized according to the size of its container. As a result, often the height of the control is not an exact multiple of the height of a single line of text. If the control contains more text than will fit in its area, it will only show as many lines as it can show fully--the next line, which could be shown clipped, is instead entirely hidden.

This is confusing to users who may not notice that there is a scrollbar, thinking that the empty space at the bottom of the control indicates that there is no more text.

How can I create a multi-line text control of some sort which does not exhibit this behavior? I am able to include a DLL and use a third-party control if that is required.

Comment: You possibly cannot do this. Why do you believe it is possible?

Comment: For a clue that you can't see the DrawText function.

Comment: I phrased the question slightly wrong (edited now)—I don't care whether I use the built-in control or something else, I just have no idea how to search for an alternative. (Searches like "windows improved multi line text control" and "windows alternative to multi line text control" didn't produce any useful results, only general discussions about the control, most of them WPF or WinForms specific.)

Comment: I was looking for the same thing, but read-only and no text wrapping were OK for me, so instead of a CEdit control I used CListBox which displays the partial lines that I wanted. Why CEdit behaves differently is beyond me, gotta love MFC.